# Tomcat and Apache Webserver using SSL on one machine

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have tomcat installed and running on an ubuntu 12.04 LTS system utilizing port 443 for https requests (GeoTrust certificate installed).

On the same machine, apache2 responds to requests on port 80.

Now I was given to task to secure the webapps (php) running on apache2 with SSL as well, but with a different server certificate.

Is this possible at all? - My assumption would be "no", because I cannot have two servers listening on the same port, but I'm not too sure and haven't found any helpful information about this so far.

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, you'll still have difficulty serving more than one certificate on a single interface/port combination (e.g. 0.0.0.0:443). IF you want to use two separate ports for HTTPS, it's no problem. If you want to bind to different interfaces (e.g. 1.2.3.4:443 and 4.3.2.1:443) it's no problem. If you want them both on the same interface/port, you'll have to rely on Server Name Indication which may or may not be supported by your web server version and/or client.

If you want different certificates, you probably want different hostnames, too, so maybe you can get a second interface configured on the machine. Note that you don't need to have multiple NICs on the machine just to enable a different interface: your OS should be able to create another interface with a different IP address and still share the NIC. Then you just set DNS to point each hostname to a different IP address and make sure you bind each SSL VirtualHost to the proper IP address (instead of using `0.0.0.0` or `*` for the hostname).

Honestly, SNI is the easiest thing to do: just use VirtualHosts with SSL enabled (with different certs) in each one the way you'd "expect" it to work and see if the server starts up without complaint. If so, you'll need to test your clients to see if it's going to work for your audience. For the SNI scenario, I am assuming that Apache httpd would handle all of the SSL traffic and that you'd use something like `mod_proxy_*` or `mod_jk` to proxy to Tomcat.

For the split-IP scenarios, you can do whatever you want: terminate SSL within Tomcat or use httpd for everything and proxy for dynamic content to Tomcat.